# Outdated mysql api in php.ini when latest one is installed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, cpanel, whm

I've issue with installation of one script on dedicated server.
I've cPanel with WHM. I've installed latest MySQL 5.6 from EasyApache and installed mysqli extension.

All is great to that moment, however when I'm checking if all is correct I've got info:
**MySQL 5 >= 5.0 is required!**

In my phpmyadmin I've got inforamtion that I've vesion **MySQL 5.6.22**.

I fight with this issue from few days. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: where are you checking? what are you checking which is returning the error?

Comment: you may need to restart your server, if you've only just installed the new MySQL

Comment: Are you talking about the mysql client error phpmyadmin throws up?

Comment: @Martin
I've restarted server and it doesn't helped. I'm checking it in test server script and also after installation it doesn't work.

Comment: @Machavity I've got error with mysql in php script